# Ajax request with jquery not populating the table on IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-11

I am transforming an old existing PHP code to generate HTML and populate a table using AJAX, for pagination and dynamic search. Due to the existing structure, my PHP page will respond all the HTML content of the table (TR and TDs), and not only the data.

I use the jQuery API `.html()` to insert the `data $('#myTable').empty().html(data)`, and I tried with `document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = data`.

My problem is that, only on Internet Explorer, the table is not populated. Both methods run perfectly with every browser I tested, but none with IE. I am using IE11. At testing the results, my page returns the good result, and a console.log(data) is good.

I found an element who might not be the answer, but when my HTML content is on an echo, table's populating works, and when I break PHP to write proper HTML, it doesn't work. Even if the result is exactly the same, obviously.

**The two methods in PHP :**

**the working one**

```
if(isset($_GET['ajax']) AND $_GET['ajax']=='displayContent')
{
    echo '<tr><td>COL1</td><td>COL2</td></tr>';
    exit;
}
```

**the not working**

```
if(isset($_GET['ajax']) AND $_GET['ajax']=='displayContent')
{
    ?>
    <tr><td>COL1</td><td>COL2</td></tr>
    <?php
    exit;
}
```

**The jQuery code :**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "?p=operation&ajax=displayContent",
        data: generateGet(),
        type: 'GET',
        async: true
    }).done(function( data){
        $( "#myTable" ).empty().html(data);
        //document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = data;
    });
```

**The HTML**

```
<table id="myTable" border="0" width="880" cellspacing="0">
    </table>
```

As far as, to me, an ECHO or writing exiting the PHP tags is exactly the same, I really don't know how to fix my issue.

I can't rewrite all the code using echo, there are really lots of lines and of code.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: If you console.log the response (`data`) are the strings the same for both scripts?

Comment: I suggest you to post complete non working code

Comment: The request is the same, I used console.log with my function generateGet() and the URL. The response is always <tr><td>COL1</td><td>COL2</td></tr> on a console.log(data).

Comment: This code is not working. The complete code is really too big, and it's not working even isolated.

Comment: It should work in both case. There will be some other error. It does not matter, how do you echos it, the point of this only the response for the ajax.

Comment: try with this code `$('#myTable').append(data);`

Comment: That's the same with append().

Comment: Possibly not related, but why are you using both a query string in the url and the `data` parameter? What does `generateGet()` return?

Comment: p=operation&ajax=displayContent  should be set in data

Comment: Yes, I already tried this, or writing all my data on the URL and not using GET. Didn't change anything.

Comment: if console.log(data); return is correct then the error is outside of the php part. You sure create a correct table with the result?

Comment: Yes, the table is generated in HTML (I edited the question, with the declaration of the table). My javascript code has just to insert some HTML content in the table. That HTML content is given by the PHP file.